# When an exception is thrown by an action method, it appears as PropertyNotFoundException

Tags: exception, jsf-2, facelets

Our application is JSF2 based and we are desiging a exception handling for that. I tried using JSF2 exception handling framework configured in `faces-config.xml`.

When I throw a null pointer from backing bean, which is referred in Facelets page, then it is coming to exception handling function as `javax.el.PropertyNotFoundException` and also it doesn't have any other stack trace about.

Is there any way to get the exact cause of the exception and the stack trace?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That will happen when the action method is called from inside a composite component. This is already been reported as [JSF issue 1806](http://java.net/jira/browse/JAVASERVERFACES-1806) which is scheduled to be fixed for JSF 2.2.

As far now, there's no way to get the root cause in the exception handler, because it's completely swallowed. Your best bet is using a separate logger or, as a hacky workaround, to pass the exception as a request attribute yourself.

Comment: Thanks BalusC , any idea when JSF2.2 is released.   Any recommendations for logger around jsf framework...

Comment: per the linked jsf issue, this has been fixed since 2.0.4-b11 `Fix Version/s:  2.0.4-b11, 2.1.10, 2.2.0-m04`

Answer (score 0):

Enabling the Development mode usually gives better error information.

Add the following to your web.xml.

```
<context-param>
   <param-name>javax.faces.PROJECT_STAGE</param-name>   
   <param-value>Development</param-value>
</context-param>
```

However you should turn this off for your production.

Comment: We do have the javax.faces.PROJECT_STAGE as development in web.xml. But still it is showns as "facesexception" rather than actual exception, is there any other configuration needs to be set.

Comment: You should check BalusC's bug link. However you said backing bean and not composite component. When we are having issues then we usually get our stacktrace.

Comment: Is there anyway to get the stack trace in single place .